# Jquery: Checking to see if any input elements were filled within a div tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a  tag and within that div that I have multiple  elements. Is there a way where I can check to see if any of those input elements were filled in ?

To add to it, the reason I am doing this is because I have a huge form divided into 4  tags which takes care of different section. I want to run validation for this section only when something is inputted by the user. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: dude, post your code or some representation of your code.

Comment: right now its just bunch of input elements withing a div tag. so think of it like <div id "mySection> <input id "something"> ""multiple divs and inputs within this section and then the closing </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
<div class="input_container">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
</div>
<div class="input_container">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
</div>
<div class="input_container">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
    <input name="something">
</div>
```

you can use jquery like this:

```
$(".input_container").each(function () {
    //iterates over each INPUT CONTAINER

    $(this).children('input').each(function () {
        //iterates over each INPUT element
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            alert("Not filled in");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: one question ...what if i have radiobuttons too ...would it work